# How to describe projective normality of a toric variety in terms of a fan?

Tags: toric-varieties

Correct me if I am wrong, but my understanding of projective normality is that if you embed the toric variety in projective space, then it is normal (i.e. the ring of functions is integrally closed.) Is this correct?

I would like to know if looking at a fan, can you use geometric properties in a simple way to determine if the corresponding toric variety is projectively normal?

Thanks,